# Javascript data needs to display HTML output as columns once the following year is evaluated

Tags: javascript, c#, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have data from last 3 years that I need to display as YEARS for each column.

In C# /asp.net  I am looping through and getting all the data and then in javascript I end up looping through the data and then just appending rows to a table.

The problem with this is that since the data goes from 2015 records to then onto 2014 and then 2013 that I will end up with 1 column and many rows

However I want to break it about and show it as

`2015    2014    2013
  a        a       a
  b        b       b`

Thus how can I do that with the data?  I though about Pivoting the data, and I though about div tags , but nothing seems that clear to me

**Mockup**

[image]

**Update**

I see in another project that this was done in angular (not relevant to my issue)    but the way in which it was done was to assume that there was ALWAYS data in each month folder for each year,  however, this is not the case to which I have only 4 months to display for 2015

Example of the existing code:

```
<table class="table-light">
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="year in years"><h2>{{ year }}</h2></th>
    </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="month in months">
        <td ng-repeat="year in years" class="text-center">
            <!-- directory path predicted based on history -->
            <a target="_blank" class="link"
               href="http://Logs\{{ year }} LOGS\{{ month.number }} - {{ year }}\&file=pdf">{{ month.title }}</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Update 2**

My data from chrome console looks like this

[image]

Then what I have showing on the web page ends up showing the 2015 months with data, but then It shows that I have files in the month January thus it is getting displayed

3 months from 2015 then 1 month of 2016  , so thus my c# code is correctly knowing to only return the month folders which have files, but I want to arrange them into 3 columns  ( I want to display 3 years  2016, 2015, 2014)

[image]

I only want to show 1 distinct month if a month contains 1 to many files thus the logic in the javascript below

```
var strResult = "";
            var month = "";

            var final = "";

            strResult = "<table class='table-light' id='myTableId'><thead><tr><th style='text-align:left;'><h2>2015</h2></th></tr></thead><tbody>";



            var unique = {};
            var distinct = [];
            for (var i in files) {
                if (typeof (unique[files[i].shortMonth]) === "undefined") {
                    distinct.push(files[i].shortMonth);
                  //   do the work here
                    month = files[i].month;
                    if (month === "" || month === null) {
                        month = "";
                    }
                    strResult += "<tr><td><a target='blank' class='link ng-binding' href='files.html?id=sub&year=" + files[i].year + "&month=" + files[i].shortMonth + "' onclick=\"getFiles('" + files[i].year + "','" + files[i].shortMonth + "');\">" + month + "</a></td></tr>";
                    final += month + ",";


                }
                unique[files[i].shortMonth] = 0;

            }
```

So hopefully that makes more sense as I know how to loop through javascript, but I want to end up displaying the html with the "look" of the screenshot under the word  **Mockup**

However, with the caveat that that the reality is the data as it stands will really only show

`2016        2015         2014
 January     August       July
             September    August
             October      December`

Comment: It will be helpful if you could rephrase the question and add some pieces of code showing us with what you are struggling.

Comment: Ok,  let me work on that   thx

Comment: Yes. At least showing what format the data are in (structure, etc.).

Comment: Ok, I hope that this is now clear on my data and what I want to do